# IOS Share extension: how to read from notes posts

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, ios8-share-extension

I want my app to be able to parse text from notes app post as well other text editors posts, so i created an share extension target. Everything worked fine until i prepare the app for publish, replacing the `TRUEPREDICATE` by 
NSExtensionActivationRule.

Supposedly, in my share extension target, i should add NSExtensionActivationSupportsText key to NSExtensionActivationRule in info.plist, which i did, but still my app extension doesn't show up in the share sheet.

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html my info.plist should contain this:

```
<key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
<dict>
   <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
   <dict> 
        <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
   </dict>
</dict>
```

I try enable also other types like attachments, files, web pages, but had no effect.

Comment: Are you running on simulator?, Also do you have the following key set NSExtensionPointIdentifier to com.apple.share-services

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At least in iOS 9, the correct code is

```
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

For reference, this is typically what it would like for text share extension support:

```
<key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationUsesStrictMatching</key>
    <integer>2</integer>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationDictionaryVersion</key>
        <integer>2</integer>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Just having "NSExtensionActivationSupportsText " didn't work, but adding "NSExtensionActivationDictionaryVersion" works for me. Thanks!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Even after adding "NSExtensionActivationSupportsText" and "NSExtensionActivationDictionaryVersion" its not working. My app is not listed under share sheet in notes after adding both of them.

Comment: NSExtensionActivationDictionaryVersion works. Strange, I added all the keys from https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html, without the dictionary version, it still doesn't show up in notes. So my conclusion is that the whole list is not properly documented.

Comment: @DGoogly I was puzzled too, and then in my case solved this by removing the entry `NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMaxCount` which had value `2`.