# NSExtensionActivationRule for iOS Share Extension is not working

Tags: ios, safari, ios-extensions, ios-sharesheet

I am working on an app extension, that should help me to get the article URL via the sharesheet in the amazon app or in safari when surfing amazon.

For safari, I receive the info as type kUTTypeURL. From Amazon, I get the URL as type kUTTypeText. As long as I haven't set up the NSExtensionActivationRule in the info.plist, it worked fine. Now it only works for Safari, but not for Amazon. This is my current plist:

[image]

I added the DictionaryVersion as I want to avoid that it is not working because Amazon doesn't provides URL and Text - but my App is not showing up any more in the sharesheet for Amazon.

I already checked help on stackoverflow, e.g. [IOS Share extension: how to read from notes posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548322/ios-share-extension-how-to-read-from-notes-posts/35753043), and also the apple documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me when setting up the plist like this:
[image]